# Django: combining inputs from multiple text boxes into single field

Tags: python, django

I have developed a Django project for students marksdata entry. Unfortunately the entry should be for each subject and EACH QUESTION.I have varying number of question in each subjects. In order to facilitate easy data entry, I have planned for multiple textboxes which are inside a html table upon submitting, the values from these multiple textboxes should be joined with comma and stored in a single a field in the database.

I have provided my views, model and template codes as below:

views.py:

```
def savemark(request):
    if request.POST:
        subject=request.POST.get("subject")
        subdata = Subject.objects.filter(subid=subject)
        course=request.POST.get("course")
        year=request.POST.get("year")
        cohart=request.POST.get("cohart")
        exam=request.POST.get("exam")
        examdata = Exam.objects.filter(examid=exam)
        qddata=Questiondetails.objects.filter(subid=subject,examtype=exam)
        studata=Studentcohart.objects.filter(cohartid=cohart,currentyear=year).values('studentid')
      return render(request,'blog/savemarks.html',{'student':studata,'question':qddata,'subject': subdata,'exam':examdata,'course':course,'year':year,'cohart':cohart})
    else:
        return render(request,'blog/home.html')
```

models.py

```
    class Mark(models.Model):
        year = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        mark = models.IntegerField()
        subid = models.ForeignKey('Subject', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='subID')  # Field name made lowercase.
        studentid = models.ForeignKey('Student', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='studentID')  # Field name made lowercase.
        examid = models.ForeignKey(Exam, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='examID')  # Field name made lowercase.
        cohartid = models.ForeignKey(Cohart, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='cohartID')  # Field name made lowercase.

class Studentcohart(models.Model):
    studentid = models.ForeignKey(Student, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='studentID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    currentyear = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cohartid = models.ForeignKey(Cohart, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='cohartID')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'studentcohart'
    def __str__(self):
       return u'%s %s %s' % (self.studentid,self.currentyear,self.cohartid)


class Subject(models.Model):
    subid = models.CharField(db_column='subID', primary_key=True, max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
    subname = models.CharField(db_column='subName', max_length=100)  # Field name made lowercase.
    year = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    cohartid = models.CharField(db_column='cohartID', max_length=20)  # Field name made lowercase.
    courseid = models.ForeignKey(Course, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='courseID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    staffname = models.CharField(db_column='staffname', max_length=50)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'subject'
    def __str__(self):
       return u'%s  %s %s %s %s %s' % (self.cohartid,self.year,self.courseid,self.subid,self.subname,self.staffname)

class Questiondetails(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(db_column='id', primary_key=True, max_length=6)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    totalnoofquestions=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    MCQ=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    SA=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    SBA=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    subid = models.ForeignKey('Subject', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='subjectID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    examtype = models.ForeignKey(Exam, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='examType')  # Field name made lowercase.
    cohartid = models.ForeignKey(Cohart, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='cohartID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    courseid = models.ForeignKey(Course, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='courseID')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Questiondetails'

    def __str__(self):
       return u'%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s' % (self.id,self.cohartid,self.year,self.examtype,self.courseid,self.subid,self.totalnoofquestions,self.MCQ,self.SBA,self.SA)

class Exam(models.Model):
    examid = models.IntegerField(db_column='examID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    examname = models.CharField(db_column='examName', max_length=20)  # Field name made lowercase.
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'exam'
    def __str__(self):
       return u'%s %s %s' % (self.examid,self.examname,self.type)
```

savemarks.html

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<form action="/submit/" method="post" >
    <tr>
        <th>studentid</th>
{% for i in "x"|rjust:"30" %}
<th>Q{{forloop.counter}}</th>
{% endfor %}
</th>q{{forloop.counter}}<th> 
    </tr>
{% for sub in student%}
<tr> 
<td>
    {{ sub.studentid}}
</td>
{% for i in "x"|rjust:"30" %}
<td> 
<input type="text" name="mark" /><br />
</td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
<table>
<input type="submit" value="Log In"/> 
</form>

<p><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log out</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

I dont know how to implement splitting a field into multiple textboxes and collecting the data back to db. Please someone guide me how to achieve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest using a related objects as questions instead of manually trying to merge the data into one field.

Comment: Thanks. Could u plz expand a bit how to handle questions as related object?

Comment: Sure, however it seems there are some models missing (`Exam`, `Questiondetails`, `Studentcohart` and `Subject`). Could you please provide with those as well so I can see some context in your data structure?

Comment: Thanks for coming forward to help. I have updated models with rest of the details.